# Evaluating iterator inside each do block in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to iterate through my array separated by white space:

```
diff_attr = []

%w[name hours].each do |a|
  if @old_place.a != new_place[a.to_sym]
    diff_attr << a
  end
end
```

I want to compare attributes (name and hours) of two different objects. Right now, I'm getting an undefined method 'a' error. Right now, a is being evaluated as a method of @old_place instead of as a variable.

How do I evaluate the iterator inside the block so that I'm comparing:

`@old.place.name != new_place[:name]`

instead of

`@old.place.a != new_place[:a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can either do it like you're doing for `new_place` (assuming both are ActiveRecord objects):

```
if @old_place[a] != new_place[a]
```

Or, use `Object#send`:

```
if @old_place.send(a) != new_place.send(a)
```

Comment: Thanks bricker. I just figured this out as well. Will checkmark your answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me.

Answer (score 1):

While another option is to simply not be afraid and use eval in Ruby:

```
diff_attr = []

%w[name hours].each do |a|
  if eval("@old_place.#{a}") != new_place[a.to_sym]
    diff_attr << a
  end
end
```